# How to create an array of character lines while reading a whole line from file in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

```
fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("textfiles\\easy.txt", FileMode.Open, filestorage));
var obj = App.Current as App;
var lines = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
obj.textfile = (string[])fileReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Getting an error

> "cannot convert string to string[]" in obj.textfile =
>   (string[])fileReader.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of lines from a single string, you can do

```
var arrayOfLines = lines.split("\n");
```